# Wiki beginner tutorials changed

Tags: ros, wiki, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was working through the beginner tutorials and noticed that they changed last night. The ROS tutorials now are specific to catkin. Nothing about services, messages or creating publishers and subscribers. What is the procedure for undoing changes to the wiki?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65602/wiki-beginner-tutorials-changed/) by [Brent Bailey](https://answers.ros.org/users/5196/brent-bailey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2013-06-20**:
Just noticed this as well.  The new tutorials are an excellent in depth look at Catkin, but I think they're a terrible intro to ROS as a whole.  Hopefully this sees a change soon, or I'm going to be writing ROS tutorials by memory for those I work with and teach...

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2013-06-20**:
I just looked through the changelogs, and found the change that broke things.  I am investigating the process for reverting the wiki...

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-06-20**:
Just a note - the roscpp/rospy tutorials are still on the wiki, just not linked from the most logical place.  (And yeah, thirding that having people start learning that much about catkin as the first step is awful! I'd switch over to the roscpp tutorials after about step 2 or 3 of catkin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's fixed, the change that caused this has been reverted.  The reason for the change was definitely valid (a tutorial on making a catkin workspace is indeed helpful) it was merely implemented poorly, and it replaced the normal tutorials with catkin ones instead of just adding the one catkin tutorial that made sense there.  Enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) with karma: 422 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2